# Turn Based Movement Algorithm

Tags: python, pygame

I am programming a turn-based strategy, like Fire Emblem, game in Python using pygame, but I am running into a problem with movement of players. The way that it works is that you select a player and it will show you all allowed moves highlighted in Blue, but my problem is that I am having a problem coming up with a list for all possible moves.

```
def showPerson(tilex, tiley, personAtTile):
global ALLOWEDMOVES
ALLOWEDMOVES = []
prepare = {k:v for v,k in PLAYERSPOSITION.items()}
z = PLAYERDISTANCE[personAtTile]
#get all coords for the possible moves
currentNewSpots = []
oldSpots = []
a = PLAYERSPOSITION[personAtTile][0]
b = PLAYERSPOSITION[personAtTile][1]
c = a + 1
test = findTileLetter(c, b)
if test:
    currentNewSpots.append((c, b))
    ALLOWEDMOVES.append((c, b))
c = a -1
test = findTileLetter(c, b)
if test:
    currentNewSpots.append((c, b))
    ALLOWEDMOVES.append((c, b))
c = b + 1
test = findTileLetter(a, c)
if test:
    currentNewSpots.append((a, c))
    ALLOWEDMOVES.append((a, c))
c = b - 1
test = findTileLetter(a, c)
if test:
    currentNewSpots.append((a, c))
    ALLOWEDMOVES.append((a, c))

for x in range(PLAYERDISTANCE[prepare[(tilex, tiley)]]):
    for y in range(len(currentNewSpots) - 1):
        a = currentNewSpots[y][0]
        b = currentNewSpots[y][1]
        c = a + 1
        test = findTileLetter(c, b)
        if test and ((c, b)) not in ALLOWEDMOVES:
            currentNewSpots.append((c, b))
            ALLOWEDMOVES.append((c, b))
        c = a -1
        test = findTileLetter(c, b)
        if test and ((c, b)) not in ALLOWEDMOVES:
            currentNewSpots.append((c, b))
            ALLOWEDMOVES.append((c, b))
        c = b + 1
        test = findTileLetter(a, c)
        if test and ((c, b)) not in ALLOWEDMOVES:
            currentNewSpots.append((a, c))
            ALLOWEDMOVES.append((a, c))
        c = b - 1
        test = findTileLetter(a, c)
        if test and ((c, b)) not in ALLOWEDMOVES:
            currentNewSpots.append((a, c))
            ALLOWEDMOVES.append((a, c))
```

Comment: I dont understand the criteria for "allowed" moves

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've asked a Python question, but your code isn't indented properly. Whitespace is syntactically significant in Python, and without proper indentation, we can't tell what your code is doing and so can't help you. Please edit your question and fix the indentation. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the game uses pathfinding, perhaps best-first-search to calculate moves. A great intro on pathfinding : http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/

Comment: What are you supposed to see? What do you actually see? It's not entirely clear what's wrong here. Additionally, if you already have one of `personAtTile` or `prepare`, what's the purpose of the other?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being very clear, and sorry for the poor indentation, something got screwed up when I copied and pasted. But atomicinf did a great job at answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I don't know what you have in mind, I'll proceed under the following assumptions:

- `findTileLetter(x, y)` tells me if the square at `(x, y)` is passable. That is, it tells me if a unit could pass through or end their turn on that square.
- Units can step up to `PLAYERDISTANCE[unit] + 1` times per turn. Each step can be taken up, down, left, or right. Diagonal steps are not allowed, but instead must be accomplished by stepping e.g. left and up.

With that in mind, we note that on the line

```
for y in range(len(currentNewSpots) - 1):
```

you iterate over one *fewer* element of `currentNewSpots` than you should, and thus every `x` loop you omit stepping from the element in `currentNewSpots` that was added *last* in the preceding `x` loop. Hence you leave out potential destination squares.

Changing the line to

```
for y in range(len(currentNewSpots))
```

fixes this issue.

Additionally, your delta-y tests in the `y` loop are not quite right:

```
    c = b + 1
    test = findTileLetter(a, c)
    if test and ((c, b)) not in ALLOWEDMOVES: ### <--- should be (a, c)
        currentNewSpots.append((a, c))
        ALLOWEDMOVES.append((a, c))
```

---

Blob of working test code follows. The `grid` defines a world of tiles: `0` tiles are impassable, while `1` tiles are passable. The `MY_X` and `MY_Y` define where we're searching from. After every step, we output the map to stdout, illustrating which squares we've found so far.

```
import sys

MY_X = 3
MY_Y = 4
MY_RNG = 2

grid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]

def findTileLetter(x, y):
    return grid[y][x]

class Person:
    pass

def showMap():
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        for x in range(len(grid[y])):
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                sys.stdout.write(' ')
            elif x == MY_X and y == MY_Y:
                sys.stdout.write('x')
            elif (x, y) in ALLOWEDMOVES:
                sys.stdout.write('o')
            else:
                sys.stdout.write('-')
        sys.stdout.write('\n')

me = Person()

ALLOWEDMOVES = []

PLAYERDISTANCE = {}
PLAYERDISTANCE[me] = MY_RNG

PLAYERSPOSITION = {}
PLAYERSPOSITION[me] = (MY_X, MY_Y)

def showPerson(tilex, tiley, personAtTile):
    global ALLOWEDMOVES
    ALLOWEDMOVES = []
    prepare = {k:v for v,k in PLAYERSPOSITION.items()}
    z = PLAYERDISTANCE[personAtTile]
    #get all coords for the possible moves
    currentNewSpots = []
    oldSpots = []
    a = PLAYERSPOSITION[personAtTile][0]
    b = PLAYERSPOSITION[personAtTile][1]
    c = a + 1
    test = findTileLetter(c, b)
    if test:
        currentNewSpots.append((c, b))
        ALLOWEDMOVES.append((c, b))
    c = a -1
    test = findTileLetter(c, b)
    if test:
        currentNewSpots.append((c, b))
        ALLOWEDMOVES.append((c, b))
    c = b + 1
    test = findTileLetter(a, c)
    if test:
        currentNewSpots.append((a, c))
        ALLOWEDMOVES.append((a, c))
    c = b - 1
    test = findTileLetter(a, c)
    if test:
        currentNewSpots.append((a, c))
        ALLOWEDMOVES.append((a, c))

    showMap()

    for x in range(PLAYERDISTANCE[prepare[(tilex, tiley)]]):
        for y in range(len(currentNewSpots)):
            a = currentNewSpots[y][0]
            b = currentNewSpots[y][1]
            c = a + 1
            test = findTileLetter(c, b)
            if test and ((c, b)) not in ALLOWEDMOVES:
                currentNewSpots.append((c, b))
                ALLOWEDMOVES.append((c, b))
            c = a - 1
            test = findTileLetter(c, b)
            if test and ((c, b)) not in ALLOWEDMOVES:
                currentNewSpots.append((c, b))
                ALLOWEDMOVES.append((c, b))
            c = b + 1
            test = findTileLetter(a, c)
            if test and ((a, c)) not in ALLOWEDMOVES:
                currentNewSpots.append((a, c))
                ALLOWEDMOVES.append((a, c))
            c = b - 1
            test = findTileLetter(a, c)
            if test and ((a, c)) not in ALLOWEDMOVES:
                currentNewSpots.append((a, c))
                ALLOWEDMOVES.append((a, c))
        showMap()

showPerson(MY_X, MY_Y, me)
print ALLOWEDMOVES
```

Comment: Wow those simple little mistakes is what fixed my whole problem, thanks! :) To be quite honest I had been working at this for almost a week and was quite confused after reviewing my code multiple times, and after trying to find a new solution online, I was getting quite tired, so thanks again.